# validate the kubernetes version using regex

Tags: regex, bash

I am looking for the right regex to validate the kubernetes version before i create the cluster. here are few examples kubernetes version. Can somebody please help on finding the right regex.

```
    1.18.6-gke.4801",
    1.17.9-gke.1504
    1.17.9-gke.6300
```

Comment: `\d+\.\d+\.\d+-gke\.\d+`

Comment: Are you looking for specific versions?

Comment: I am  not looking for a specific version. it should always comply with the all the mentioned version type.

Comment: not sure if bash support \d, so  can i try using [0-9] instead of \d:

Comment: Please add your desired output (no description) for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: Have you really tried any regex?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You might want to try something like this:

```
if [[ $GKE_VERSION =~ ^[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]-gke\.[0-9]+$ ]]; then
    echo "OK: Good GKE Version: ${BASH_REMATCH[0]}"
else
    echo "Bad GKE Version"
fi
```

Or something like this may be:

```
[[ "1.17.9-gke.1504" =~ ^[0-9]{,2}\.[0-9]{,2}\.[0-9]{,2}-gke\.[0-9]{4}$ ]] && echo "Good GKE Version" || echo "Bad GKE Version"
```